# Approval Process Not Respecting Else Approve Step

Tags: apex, visualforce, approval-process, approval-step

## Question

Is there any known issue with the approval process steps that have criteria that enter if it evaluates to true, else approve, auto-rejecting records that don't meet the criteria?  If so, are there work arounds?  (hoping to avoid a week of waiting on support just to have them tell me this bug is a "feature" they don't want to change)

## Background

I have a moderately complex approval process, which at a high level has these steps:

1. If picklist is value A, send to User1__c on the record, else next step
2. If picklist is value B, send to User2__c on the record, else approve
3. If false (dummy step, should always be skipped in theory)

In testing I submit a record with a pikclist with value C.  Based on my understanding the flow is:

1. Evaluate criteria for step 1, eval = false, go to next step
2. Evaluate criteria for step 2, eval = false, approve

But in testing, it always auto-rejects.  Reviewing the logs confirms it skips step 1, hits step 2, then rejects.  Also confusing is that when I edit step 2 it shows "else approve", but on the approval process detail it just shows the criteria, with no "else" clause (see images).  The view approval process also looks good to me.

## Images

### Process Detail Page

[image: Process Detail Page]

### Step 2 Criteria

[image: Step 2 Detail]

### Printable Process Diagram

[image: Process Diagram]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [Creating Approval Steps](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_steps.htm&language=en_US) section Important:

> If you select go to next step in the first step and the record does not meet the criteria for any of the steps in the approval process, the record is rejected.

Suggested solution:

Create two approval processes.

1. First with entry criteria for picklist **equals** A, B with two steps.
2. Second with entry criteria for picklist **not equals** A, B with one
   step.

[image: First approval process]
[image: Second approval process]

Comment: Facepalm, it was right there, thank you!! Now if only the user interface reflected the docs, would have saved us all some time